# How to validate GET url parameters through ModelState with data annotation

Tags: c#, validation, rest, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I have a Web API project... I would like to respect the REST principles, so I should have just a GET method and just a POST method... 
I have to do a search, so i think this matches the GET method, because after the search I obtain the result and I show it in the page... If I do not find anything I must create the object... this action is a POST...

Now I have a problem... I must validate the filters of the search, because filters are a tax code and a alpha-numeric code (6 chars)... I have already done a client side validation. Now I should do a Server Side validation.

Untill now, we have used data annotation to validate the request, but this is a GET... so my method has this signature:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetActivationStatus(string taxCode, string requestCode)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

But how can I validate my ModelState with Data Annotation?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717250/is-it-possible-to-use-data-annotations-to-validate-parameters-passed-to-an-actio/2717270#2717270

Comment: yes, I think you are right... But the solution is really orrible... do you suggest another kind of validation? For example, "Fluent Validation" could help me? Or there is a way to pass a complex object with a GET ?

Comment: You're passing primitives. How do you expect to validate model state on them? You're either going to have to make a model and decorate it or do a custom action attribute that validates the action args.

Comment: I cannot do a model... It's a GET request

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create your own model...

```
public class YourModel 
{
    [//DataAnnotation ...]
    public string taxCode { get; set; }
    [//DataAnnotation ...]
    public string requestCode { get; set; }
}
```

And change your signature of your server side controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetActivationStatus([FromUri] YourModel yourmodel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

If your client side code already worked you don't have to change it... Please, note that the properties of your Model are the same of the parameter you are passing now (`string taxCode, string requestCode`)... and they are case sensitive...

**EDIT**:
I mean that you can call your controller in this way:

http://localhost/api/values/?taxCode=xxxx&requestCode=yyyy